# AmazonDynamoDBException - User Not Authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to integrate Spring Boot with DynamoDB and seems like i am running into the access denied issue.

Here is what I have already done

- Created a new user
- Created a user group and assigned the user to the group.
- Created the policy with the access to dynamodb as a resource for put, get and delete.
- Assigned the policy to the user group

I am still not able to understand why the programmatic connection to dynamodb is providing me access denied.

Here is source code for the config  class.

```
public class DynamoDbConfig {

    @Value("${aws.access.key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${aws.access.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${aws.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String awsDynamoDBEndPoint;

    @Value("${aws.region:}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials(){
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    }

    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialsProvider(){
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(amazonAWSCredentials());
    }

    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(){
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(awsDynamoDBEndPoint, awsRegion))
                .withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper mapper(){
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB());
    }
```

Already checked it out that the config properties are being loaded correct.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve this.

Attach the AWS managed Full DynamoDB Access policy to the group. For development or POC purposes it is ok but its a best practice to restrict the access to the resource through the policy.

This is what I did to gave access

```
"Action": [
                "sns:Publish",
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
```